# Migrate ssl certificates by ACME.SH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, lets-encrypt

If I want migrate ssl certificates generated by acme.sh.

1. I install acme.sh on new server
2. Paste folders (example.com, nextdomain.com, ...) with certs to new
   server to the same path (.acme.sh)

Could it be a problem with a new acme letsencrypt account or not?
Could I replace all folder acme.sh (with account info, etc) or does ot matter ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
after you install it on your new machine, you can just  copy your old `~/.acme.sh` to the new machine.
It should work.